# Bootstrapping accuracy, f1-score?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bootstrap, train

I have typical train/test setting, with an ordinary dataset. As I am comparing performance of two approaches to a problem (namely churn prediction with `AdaBoost` and `BG/NBD`), I would like to estimate the confidence intervals of the results, and compare, whether accuracy scores are really higher for one approach than for the other.

To do so, I would like to use bootstrap. I am currently doing:

```
0 for n times:
1     bootstrap the training dataset,
2     fit the models,
3     use the models to predict target on test data
4     store models' accuracy, f1-score
5 compare accuracy, f1-score using two-sample t-test
```

I am not sure whether this approach makes sense. 
From my provisional results it seems that some of the distributions are not normally distributed. 
Eyeballing the results it also seems that I am able to artificially lower the variance and thus rejecting the null hypothesis.

My question is: what are the weak points of this approach? What can I improve?

Edit:
I am aware of that both accuracy and f1-score are not the best metrics for model evaluation, and therefore I decided to report apart from them also precision and recall. However, this is not mentioned in the original question, as I thought this is not necessary for the point I am trying to make. Apart from that, even though my dataset is imbalanced (38% v 62%), this proportion is not big and therefore I decided to report accuracy as well.

Comment: The downvotes to both question and answer seem unjustified without an explanation, so I'm cancelling them both out.

Comment: @mkt: I'm not complaining, but there is no expectation of explaining downvotes. [And this.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23486/51074)

Comment: @StephanKolassa I'm not opposed to unexplained downvotes in general - I do it myself. It didn't seem merited in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use accuracy to evaluate a classifier: [Why is accuracy not the best measure for assessing classification models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352) The very same arguments show that the F1 score is problematic.

Instead, use probabilistic predictions and assess these using proper [scoring-rules](/questions/tagged/scoring-rules) on holdout datasets. Do feel free to bootstrap these, or run cross-validation.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am aware of that, and therefore I decided to report apart from accuracy and f1-score also precision and recall. However, this is not mentioned in the question, as I thought this is not necessary for the point I am trying to make. Apart from that, even though my dataset is imbalanced (38% v 62%), the proportion is not big and therefore I decided to report accuracy as well.

Comment: @johnnyheineken, I understand your perspective, but this *is* an answer to your larger question. The implication is that you should not be on this path at all. That could be incorrect, of course, but it is a sincere attempt to help.

Comment: Thank you for good moderating. I can see the other perspective now.

Comment: @johnnyheineken: I understand why you might not be satisfied with my answer. [This may be informative.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5004/1352) I won't hold it against you if you are still not happy. (And accuracy is also a problem with balanced datasets.)

Comment: @Kolassa.  I was satisfied with your answer.  Arguably a little terse, but arguably to the point.